# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent opensuse 13.2

Tags: android, linux, bitbucket, ssh-keys, opensuse

I try to use bitbucket for my android application. I have my repo on my account. I want to clone my project to local computer. For this I need to generate ssh key. I use this tutotial https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ . And I have error  "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." when I make command "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa". Before it I "eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" and it show "Agent pid 32426". What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I find this command, use it before add:
eval $(ssh-agent)

Note : "eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" didn't work for me also but the command "eval $(ssh-agent)" working good